# firestore onSnapshot updates values, but not DOM in VueJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, dom, google-cloud-firestore

I'm listening for real-time updates in Vue using onSnapshot. I can see the data is loading from onSnapshot, but it's not updating in the DOM. This could just be a really dumb mistake, I've only been programming for about a little over a month and I just don't understand something and my googling skills are failing me. The browser shows "No State Listed" and not the actual value from the DB and console.log.

Here are the snippets from my .Vue file.

```
        <div>
          <span class="grey--text">State:</span>
          <span class="grey--text">{{ state }}</span>
        </div>



export default {
  components: { VoterRegistration },
  data() {
    return {
      state: "No State Listed"
    };
  },
  methods: {},
  created() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        db.collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.data()); // shows all the data I want
            this.state = doc.data().state;
            console.log(this.state); //this shows correct value in firestore db
          });

        this.loggedIn = true;
      } else {
        this.person = "User not logged in";
        this.loggedIn = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try changing to arrow function?

```
db.collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data()); // shows all the data I want
            this.state = doc.data().state;
            console.log(this.state); //this shows correct value in firestore db
          });
```

I think `this` in your `function(doc)` is not Vue instance.

Comment: HA that did it! You're a genius. Thank you SOO much. I didn't realize it worked that way. I'm still learning a lot!

Comment: I'll mark this as answered in 9 minutes, it won't let me till then.